# python3.6 PEXPECT is not writing logs to a logfile

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to log pexpect logs to a file. The code was working in python2.7 but logs not getting printed in python3.6

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("telnet IP")
fout = open("abc.txt", "wb"):
child.logfile = fout
child.sendlines("somecommand)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Also, you say in a comment to shmee's answer that you added the `with` from the original version of your question when porting to 3.6. But that `with` broke the code. Is that all there is to your problem?

Comment: It means I am not getting anything in the logfile. There are another child.sendlines commands that I have not mentioned here

Comment: With the above code that I have mentioned, no logs are getting printed in python3.6.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to believe that exactly this code was working in Python 2.7 ;)

Your contextmanager exits right after `child.logfile = fout` completes, hence your file handle is closed when your child process tries to write to it afterwards.
You'll have to keep the file handle open until your child finishes, e.g.:

```
import pexpect
with open("abc.txt", "wb") as fout:
    child = pexpect.spawn("telnet IP")
    child.logfile = fout

# -- OR --

child = pexpect.spawn("telnet IP")
with open("abc.txt", "wb") as fout:
    child.logfile = fout
    child.expect(<some pattern here>)
```

Comment: You are right. I made a error while printing the code from 2.7. In 2.7 I was not using with statement. I was opening file as open("filename", "w"). I have just modified the statement while writing this in stack overflow