# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object `python3.6`

Tags: python

I am having below code

```
    for eol in ['\r\n', '\r', '\n']:
        content = re.sub('%s$' % eol, '', content)
```

Where content type is `bytes`

Content data is

```
b"Trying IP...\r\nConnected to IP.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n"
```

Content type

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

I am reading PEXECT data and this is where content coming from. It is coming from telnet terminal

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Why I am getting this error

Comment: Presumably `content` is a `bytes` or other `bytes`-like object. Since you haven't shown us what it is or where it comes from, it's hard to say more. Maybe the problem is that you called `encode` somewhere you shouldn't have, or you're using a `requests` response and used `r.content` instead of `r.text`, or you opened a file in binary mode instead of text mode. Or maybe you just need to call `decode` on `context` with the right encoding. Or maybe it really _should_ just be a `bytes`, and you just need to use a `bytes` pattern, so change all those string literals into bytes literals.

Comment: Yes content type is bytes

Comment: what is the data in content?  Can you please show it?

Comment: OK, then the error message is telling you exactly the same thing I just told you. But if that isn't enough for you to understand how to fix it, you need to give us more context—where does `content` come from, what encoding is it in, is it supposed to be a `bytes`, what do you want to do with it, etc.—so instead of giving you a half-dozen options of which none may be relevant to you, we can actually give you an answer.

Comment: My first though - content is byte-like object, not string. I'm not sure, check this.

Comment: @ZRTSIM The OP already confirmed that it's a `bytes`, and even edited that into the question. Why are you asking him to check it?

Comment: Can you look into question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51721956/python3-6-pexpect-is-not-writing-logs-to-a-logfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pexpect` can give you Unicode strings, unless you ask it to give you bytes.

If you *want* it to give you bytes—e.g., because you don't know the encoding the `telnet` server is expecting you to use—that's fine, but then you have to deal with it as bytes. That means using bytes patterns, not string patterns, in `re`:

```
for eol in [b'\r\n', b'\r', b'\n']:
    content = re.sub(b'%s$' % eol, b'', content)
```

But if you didn't want bytes, it's better to get everything decoded to `str`, and the your existing code would just work:

```
content = pexpect.run('ls -l', encoding='utf-8')
for eol in ['\r\n', '\r', '\n']:
    content = re.sub('%s$' % eol, '', content)
```

---

As a side note, if you're just trying to remove a final newline on the last line, it's a lot easier to do that without a regex:

```
content = content.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Or, if you're trying to do something different, like remove blank lines, even that might be better written explicitly:

```
content = '\n'.join(line for line in content.splitlines() if line)
```

… but that still leaves you with the same problem of needing to use `b'\n'` or `'\n'` appropriately, of course.

Comment: Hey, Can you look into my another opened question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51721956/python3-6-pexpect-is-not-writing-logs-to-a-logfile

Comment: Answer accepted because you were the first one to comment

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control the datatype of content you can use something like this.

```
for eol in [b'\r\n', b'\r', b'\n']:
    content = re.sub(b'%s$' % eol, b'', content)
```